# Save variable and use it on recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

Suppose I have the following function

```
printVariance :: [Float] -> IO ()
printVariance [] = return ()
printVariance (x:xs)
    | x >= avg (x:xs) = print (x - avg (x:xs)) >> printVariance xs
    | otherwise       = printVariance xs
```

Which gets a list, checks which elements are bigger than the average and prints their `value - avg`.

My problem is that the `avg` value changes every step. How can I define it just once and use its value for the recursion?

Comment: You might want to rewrite this using folds and maps instead of recursing directly. This would allow you to attach a `where` or a `let` binding where you'd define your `avg` as something along the lines of `(foldr (+) 0 xs) / length xs`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the recursion into a helper function. That function can either take the average as a parameter or you could define locally to `printVariance` and define another local variable holding the average, which the function could then access.

In code:

```
printVariance :: [Float] -> IO ()
printVariance xs = loop xs
  where
    average = avg xs
    loop [] = return ()
    loop (x:xs)
      | x >= average = print (x - average) >> loop xs
      | otherwise = loop xs
```

PS: It would be good design to separate the IO from the program logic. So I'd recommend you make your function simply produce a list of the values you want, rather than printing them and move the IO into a separate function (or just `main`).

PPS: You're not really calculating the variance, so I'd recommend naming the function something else.

Comment: Ah, we've written the same program. I'll delete my answer for brevity's sake :)

Comment: You nailed it, I don't know how I could not think it, thanks!